# Import error while importing MLPClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, python-3.5, python-import, importerror

I'm facing the below error when I try to run :

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
```

Error :

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-77-6113b65dfa44>", line 1, in <module>
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from .multilayer_perceptron import MLPClassifier

File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 18, in <module>
from ..model_selection import train_test_split

File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from ._search import GridSearchCV

File "C:\Users\anagha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 32, in <module>
from ..utils.fixes import rankdata

**ImportError: cannot import name 'rankdata'**
```

Comment: Are you using anaconda, or in python terminal directly? How have you installed scikit?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a working installation of numpy and scipy:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

otherwise:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

finally check for updates:

```
conda update pip
```